# gnome-terminal not working (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: gnome-terminal

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog

Jul  3 01:04:56 arik-precision org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1543]: (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:3073): dconf-WARNING **: 01:04:56.600: Unable to open /var/lib/snapd/desktop/dconf/profile/user: Permission denied
Jul  3 01:07:02 arik-precision dbus-daemon[1417]: [session uid=1000 pid=1417] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.106' (uid=1000 pid=3285 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real " label="unconfined")
Jul  3 01:07:02 arik-precision systemd[1376]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Jul  3 01:07:02 arik-precision gnome-terminal-server[3288]: Locale not supported.
Jul  3 01:07:02 arik-precision systemd[1376]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=9/n/a
Jul  3 01:07:02 arik-precision systemd[1376]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul  3 01:07:02 arik-precision systemd[1376]: Failed to start GNOME Terminal Server.
Jul  3 01:07:27 arik-precision org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1543]: # Locale not supported by C library.
Jul  3 01:07:27 arik-precision org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1543]: # #011Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Jul  3 01:07:27 arik-precision org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1543]: # Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

I would appreciate any help in the matter!

Thanks,

Arik

Comment: Log into another account (create one if need be) and see if terminal works there. Report back.

Comment: Thanks. Will try. In the mean time I switched to konsole.

Comment: Where's the rest of your question?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was seeing the "Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached" error when connecting via vnc. Adding this to my ~/.vnc/xstartup resolved that:

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --all &
```

However you may need to put it in some other init file in your instance. E.g. /etc/profile or similar.